# From the locale, how do I get the currency code?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, currency-formatting

PHP has an `intl` module which allows for some cool things - like getting the currency symbol when using the [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class. But this is making a massive assumption - that you already have the currency code of the currency you want to get the symbol for.

How do I get the currency code for any specific locale?

For example: `en_gb` => `gbp`, `en_us` => `usd`, `es_es` => `eur`

I am doing this so I can use the `currencyFormat` view helper in ZendFramework 2:

```
$locale = 'en_gb'; //from get parameter
$symbol = 'GBP'; //How do get this?

$this->serviceManager
         ->get('viewhelpermanager')
         ->get('currencyFormat')
         ->setLocale($locale)
         ->setCurrencyCode($symbol);
```

Comment: You would need a map of locale codes to currency codes.  [first search result](https://gist.github.com/HarishChaudhari/4680482)

Comment: I think you need the ISO 4217 code in zend? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299099/get-currency-iso-4217-code-based-on-locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer from [Get currency ISO 4217 code based on locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47331489/351785) (thanks [@avy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5899686/avy) for link in comment),

```
$locale = 'en_gb'; //from $_GET parameter

//get symbol for this locale
$symbol = \NumberFormatter::create(
    $locale,
    \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY
)->getTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE);

//Add locale to currency formatter so we get correct symbol and formatting
$this->serviceManager
        ->get('viewhelpermanager')
        ->get('currencyFormat')
        ->setLocale($locale)
        ->setCurrencyCode($symbol);
```